# Different VF Pages for different record types on the object

Tags: visualforce

I have a scenario on a custom object called VM_Sales_Order__c with 6 record types named FAS, FSAL, ISAL, National Manager, Regional Manager and VP. Whenever I select a record type it should take me to its respective vf page. For example, when FAS record type is selected and new button is clicked it should take me to FAS VF Page.

Comment: so what did not work for you and what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are going to create separate VF page for each record type.

Here, you need to override NEW button of an Object. When you override New button with VF page, you get a selected Record Type as a parameter in the page URL. Using this record type you can redirect user to different VF pages.

The New page will contain the action method which will identify the record type and accordingly you can redirect user to different VF pages.

**Apex Class**:

```
public class NewAccountExtension {

    public String recordTypeId;

    public NewAccountExtension(ApexPages.StandardController std) {

    }

    public Pagereference redirectToNewVFPage(){
        Pagereference pg = null;
        if(ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType') != null){
            recordTypeId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType');
            if(recordTypeId == Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Household').getRecordTypeId()){
                pg = new Pagereference('/apex/Page1'); // Add Parameters to Page if Needed

            }else if(recordTypeId == Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Business').getRecordTypeId()){
                pg = new Pagereference('/apex/Page2'); // Add Parameters to Page if Needed
            }
            pg.setRedirect(true);
            return pg;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**VF Page**:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="NewAccountExtension" action="{!redirectToNewVFPage}">
</apex:page>
```

The another approach can be to create only one single VF page and create different sections for each record type. You can render each section based on the record type that you will get in the page URL as a parameter.