# Can we redirect user to different Visualforce Page when creating record based on record type?

Tags: visualforce, record-type, new

I have Custom Object **MyObject__c** and it has two different **Record Types**.

I need to redirect user to **different** Visualforce Pages based on **Record Type** he selected.

I know we can assign one visualforce page to the **New** button and then redirect user from this page to another based on record type.

Here the similar [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/144499/different-vf-pages-for-different-record-types-on-the-object/144508#144508)

[image]

**It works in this way for my now.**

[image]

However I want to know :

***Is there a way assign different Visualforce Page to different record types for the New button (without additional Redirect Page)?***

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/144508/18189) might help you

Comment: @kurunve I saw it. 
Actually  I am looking for a solution where I do not need additional redirect page.
I updated the question.